# Prove a function is onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that the function $f(x)=x^5+2x^2+x$ is onto. My teacher did an example in class were he said $f(x)=y$ and then found the inverse of the function. He then plugged the inverse back into the function and found that it equaled y. And that was the proof that the function was onto.

This makes sense, but I don't know how to find the inverse of this function and I am wondering if there is another way to prove this without finding the inverse?

Comment: Draw the graph, this follows immediately. Note that we can find the 'inverse' by flipping it about $y=x$. (However, we don't really have a function, because it is one to many.)

Comment: Have you learnt about taking limits? If so, one way to go is to prove that the image of $f$ is all $\mathbb{R}$ by noticing that $f$ is continuous, and then just take the limits of $f$ when $x \to + \infty$, and $x \to - \infty$.

Comment: You'll struggle to find an inverse, because this function doesn't have one! Instead, show that the function takes arbitrarily high and low values, and that it's continuous in between.

Comment: To elaborate more on what @user49685 said, if you have a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and we have that $f(b) > f(a)$, then for each $y$ in $[f(a),f(b)]$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. So suppose at $-\infty$ we have that $f$ is $-\infty$ and at $+\infty$, we have that $f$ is $+\infty$. What can we say, if anything, about whether or not $f$ is onto?

Comment: You will not find a nice formula for $x$ in terms of $y$. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate your function and if it either always increasing or always decreasing then it will onto. In your case it is always increasing. Following is the solution :
[image]

Comment: Please use LaTeX when writing mathematics in this site. Directions in the FAQ section.

Comment: @DonAntonio : Sorry, I am new. From next time onwards I will have this in mind.

Comment: Don't worry, @Nishant: we've all been there.

Comment: What if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = \tanh{(x)}$? $\tanh{(x)}$ is always increasing, but $f(x)$ wouldn't be [onto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onto_function)

Comment: @Nishant I think you are confusing [onto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onto_function) and [one to one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_function)

Answer (score 1):

$\,f(x) \;$ is a continuous function on the whole real line, as any other polynomial is, and since

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty\\\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$$

the intermediate value theorem tells us that for any value $\;c\in(-\infty,\infty)\,$ there exists $\,r\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t.\;\;f(r)=c\;$ .

This much is true for any real polynomial with odd degree, btw.